# Resolve Canonical issue in php

Tags: php, canonical-link

I am having site name as www.tutntips.com , i want to redirect www.tutntips.com to http://www.tutntips.com.

I having tried using `htaceess` and added the following line but still not able to redirect

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tutntips.com [nocase]

RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.tutntips.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

How can i redirect them?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Ok I got it. By Default http will not show  in URL(Internally it is included with the URL) , only https will show  in URL if site is deployed on server having HTTPS protocol